# Create a shallow copy of a single channel in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, shallow-copy

In OpenCV, it's possible to create a `cv::Mat` representing a sub-rectangle of an existing `cv::Mat`, with `cv::Mat::operator()` functions. This is made possible by the Mat `step` parameter which enables non contiguous data, allowing padding bytes in each axis.

Is it possible to have a single channel shallow copy selected in an RGB image, the same way? I can't find whether `cv::split` is a shallow or deep copy.

What I need to do is applying gaussian blur on the G channel of a RGB image. Do I necessarily have to deep copy the G channel to a single channel image first?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, at least not for the regular 2D Mats that are broadly used in OpenCV. Notice in the constructors, that the number of possible "step" parameters is 1 less than the number of dimensions (and channels are not considered a dimension). You could probably make a 3D Mat of 8UC1 (rows x cols x 1), to have a step between columns as well... but I'm not so sure how most OpenCV functions will like that.

Comment: With `cv::Mat GreenCH = SrcImg.reshape( 1, SrcImg.rows * SrcImg.cols ).col(1);`,
you can obtain `Mat` to access only green ch, but shape is not good...
So, very simple process likes "fill green ch whole with same value" can be perfomed, but blurring is...